# SQLite - Selecting the first record of a different date

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve the unique dates from the database. I want to retrieve the **one record per each unique date**.

Example of the result I expected to be:

```
paperbag
hehe
jacky
```

Below is my raw data inside my SQLite database

```
 id{PK}      name             created_on
 1      |  paperbag    | 2016-07-13 21:00:00 
 2      |  jacky       | 2016-07-29 16:00:00
 3      |    awesome   | 2016-07-15 14:13:00
 4      |     hehe     | 2016-07-15 03:00:00
 5      |     what     | 2016-07-15 04:00:00
 6      |  do you know | 2016-07-29 21:00:00
 7      |     keke     | 2016-07-15 21:00:00
```

I attempted to sort the data in ascending order. Next, I would try to SELECT DISTINCT of created_on.

Now the real problem is, how do I translate it to Android query method? Below is the method **query** I will be using.

```
public Cursor sqlGetUniqueRecord() {
    return myDataBase.query(true, tableName, columnArray, null, null, null, null, null,null);
}
```

Thank you for reading this! Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

One method to get one record per day is to use aggregation:

```
select date(created_on), max(name)
from t
group by date(created_on);
```

Comment: But how to get it done by using android query () only?